# Java using coffeine library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, caffeine-cache

[image]
[image]
I try to debug the caffeine cache, after adding a value to the cache I tried to get it as a map, invoking the asMap() method, but I never received a value, IntelliJ idea show me the message "Collecting data". I can't figure out what is wrong and how to receive value from asMap() method.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Attach screenshot and source code if possible.

Comment: Added screenshots

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: I hope it is not remote debug. I had issue with remote debuging and the collection of data was endless. Actually around 1-2minutes depends on amount of data in variable view

Comment: >`Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")? `

no, this section is clear.

Comment: `I hope it is not remote debug. I had issue with remote debuging and the collection of data was endless. Actually around 1-2minutes depends on amount of data in variable view `

No, this is a standard debug session.

Comment: Did you customize any debugger settings such as type renderers?
Do any of the settings from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799 help?

Comment: I've customized renderer only for long type